# Flipping digitized directions of geometry based on route measures using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, route, direction

I have a feature class that has a schema like:

`routeId, fromMeasure, toMeasure, attr1,attr2..etc`

within a given routeId, the segments flip directionaility many times and are not consistent. I would like to have all the geometry directions match increasing the measure of the route.

I am pretty sure I want to do the  "Set direction as M" function here https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/about-setting-route-measures.htm

I am not used to ArcMap so it's not clear to me how I can process all 20,000 segments at once and have it flip the geometry. I believe I need to convert my segment file to a route layer, and then somehow run the route editor and then somehow go from a route layer back into a segment file, perhaps with events or something.

Comment: Add geometry attributes, start, mid, end. It will populate values by relevant, x,x,z,m sets. Select by attribute StartM>EndM. Flip edit.

Comment: It fails when I add geometry attributes. I guess I need to make  a route layer and somehow add m measures?